# "Min-norm": does such an object make sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, normed-spaces

One of the widely used norms on vector spaces is the $l_\infty$ *norm* or *max-norm*; that is, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\vert\vert x\vert\vert_\infty:=\max_{i=1...n}|x_i|.
$$ 
This is a fairly classical and well-studied object. However, I'm currently wondering whether an ''opposite'', in a certain sense, object makes sense or has been studied:
$$
||x||_{-\infty}:=\min_{i=1...n}|x_i|.
$$
For a lack of a better name, it can be called *min-norm*. Intuitively, it is reasonable to consider in some applications where, for example, two objects $x, y$ are deemed to be 'close' if they are 'close' at least in one of the coordinates.

It is fairly easy to see that *min-norm* is not actually a norm, because it violates the definitiveness constraint: $\vert\vert x\vert\vert_{-\infty}=0$ does not imply $x=0$. On the other hand, *min-norm* still satisfies the two other norm axioms, the triangle inequality and positive homogenity.

My question is: has this object been previously considered in maths or applications, or why not? Or does it even make sense to study it? Any relevant links or references are highly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality either: consider $(1,0)+(0,1)=(1,1)$. It's just a random quantity, like taking square root of the sum of cosines of coordinates. You can study it if you wish.

Comment: Geometrically, it is the distance of the point $x$ from the union of the coordinate hyperplanes $x_i=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: **The triangle inequality is not fulfilled** since for $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$ it holds that
$$
\|x+y\|_{-\infty} = 1\quad\text{but}\quad \|x\|_{-\infty}+\|y\|_{-\infty} = 0.
$$

On the other hand both are somehow connected by
$$
\|x\|_\infty = \lim_{p\to\infty} \|x\|_p
$$$$
\|x\|_{-\infty} = \lim_{p\to-\infty} \|x\|_p
$$
where $\|x\|_p = (\sum_i |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ for real $p$. The functions $x\mapsto \|x\|_p$ cease to be metrics for $p<1$ already (but stay "quasi-metrics" in the sense that the triangle is fulfilled with an additional constant, at least for $0<p<1$).

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I quite honestly didn't think enough before saying that the triangle holds. I initially thought of this function in the context of metric learning for nearest-neighbor search, and was wondering whether this min-norm form of a "metric" makes sense; the fact that this is not a metric mathematically is not a killer. However, thanks a lot for pointing out the connection with the $l_p$ limit.